# If $a^{2x-1} = b^{1-3y}$ and $a^{3x-1} = b^{2y-2}$, show $13xy = 7x +5y -3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^{2x-1} = b^{1-3y}$ and  $a^{3x-1} = b^{2y-2}$, show $13xy = 7x +5y -3.$

I apologize in advance if this forum finds this question trivial but I am desperate for any help, will appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Solve for $a$ in terms of $b$ from both equations and set them equal

Comment: Some additional assumption is needed, such as $a,b\gt 1$.  If $a=b=1$, nothing can be concluded about $x$ and $y$.

Comment: But you don't need $a,b> 1$ just that $a\not 1; b \ne 1$ and actually in this case that only one or the other is not equal to one is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in [J. W. Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner)'s comment to the question, assuming that $2x - 1 \neq 0$ and $3x - 1 \neq 0$, then taking appropriate roots of both sides gives that

$$a^{2x-1} = b^{1-3y} \; \Rightarrow a = b^{\frac{1-3y}{2x-1}} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$a^{3x-1} = b^{2y-2} \; \Rightarrow a = b^{\frac{2y-2}{3x-1}} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Assuming that $b$ is not $-1,0$ or $1$, the powers of $b$ must be equal in \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2}, so

$$\frac{1-3y}{2x-1} = \frac{2y-2}{3x-1} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

You can now cross-multiply and simplify to get the requested equality, plus you will also need to show, for the cases not covered by this solution technique, that the equality still holds, or that you can't determine that it does (e.g., if $a = b = 0$ or $a = b = 1$).

Comment: Would you mind explaining your thought process when solving this problem, did you already realized that we'd have to solve the simul. eqn and the answer would show that 13xy=... ? I just couldn't seem to wrap my head around the question when they asked show that 13xy=.. I think it would help immensley if I could at least see your thought patterns when solving these type of problems.

Comment: @Antonio I didn't worry too much about what was asked to be proven. Instead, I focused on how to get to a stage to try to show it. You're initially given $2$ equations in basically $2$ unknowns of $a$ and $b$ (assuming for now that $x$ & $y$ are given). To solve them, the usual way is to try to eliminate one of the variables by simplifying the equations so that you can express one of the variables directly, and then equating those $2$ expressions. In this case, I chose $a$ by taking the first equation to the power of $\frac{1}{2x-1}$ & the second equation to the power of $\frac{1}{3x-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight into your mind @John, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Antonio You are welcome. Note one other consideration is that the final expression you're asked to prove, i.e., $13xy = 7x +5y -3$, doesn't involve $a$ or $b$. This is another clue that you should try to eliminate the $a$ and $b$ from the expressions so that only $x$ and $y$ are left, such as what I did.

Comment: Exacly what I realized upon reviewing another question about logs that I had asked here, "$\log_8(x+2)$ $+$ $\log_8y$ $=$ $z-\frac{1}{3}$ and $\log_2(x-2)$ $-$ $\log_2y$ = $2z+1$, Show that $x^2 = 32 ^z + 4 $" There isn't any $y$ hence we somehow have to eliminate it. These kinds of "novel" questions are hard to come by in a maths text book or at least the particular one I'm doing right now, most of the questions are "mechanical" just plug this or that infact this and the question I had posted had an asterisk  beside them to denote that they are special or hard lol.

Answer (score 2):

take the $\log $ for both equation if$( a>1 $ and $b>1)$
$$\frac{\log b}{\log a}=\frac{2x-1}{1-3y}$$
$$\frac{\log b}{\log a}=\frac{3x-1}{2y-2}$$
then
$$\frac{2x-1}{1-3y}=\frac{3x-1}{2y-2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers and neither equal $1$, and you have proven or other wise accepted that for every base $b >0; b\ne 1$ and and every positive real number $w$ there is exactly one real $x$ so that $b^x = w$ and we call that number $x:=\log_b w$.  And that you have define $b^y$ for any real $y$.  (Both of these are *BIG* assumptions)....

So $a^{2x-1} = b^{1-3y}$.  If $2x-1 \ne 0$ then

$(a^{2x-1})^{\frac 1{2x-1}} = (b^{1-3y})^{\frac 1{2x-1}}$

$a = b^{\frac {1-3y}{2x-1}}$.

And $a^{3x-1} = b^{2y-2}$.  So if $3x-1 = 0$ then

by the same reasoning $a = b^{\frac {2y-2}{3x-1}}$.

So $ b^{\frac {1-3y}{2x-1}}= a= b^{\frac {2y-2}{3x-1}}$ which means

$\frac {1-3y}{2x-1}=\frac {2y-2}{3x-1}$ which can easily be manipulated to:

$(1-3y)(3x-1) = (2x-1)(2y-2)$

$3x -9xy + 3y - 1 = 4xy -2y - 4x + 2$

$7x + 5y -3 = 13xy$.

BUT  We have to think what happens if $2x -1 = 0$ or $3x -1 = 0$.

If $2x-1 = 0$ then $a^{2x-1} = 1 =b^{1-3y}$ and $1-3y = 0$.  SO $x = \frac 12$ and $y = \frac 13$

And $13xy = \frac {13}6$ whil $7x + 5y - 3 = \frac 72 + 53 - 3 = \frac {21 + 10 - 18}{6} = \frac{13}6$ as well.

If $3x-1 =0$ then $a^{3x-1} = a^0 = 1 = b^{2y-2}$ so $2y-2=0$ and$x =\frac 13$ and  $y=1$.

Thus $13xy = \frac {13}3$ and $7x + 5y -3 =\frac 73 + 5-3 = \frac 73 +2 = \frac {13}3$.

====

Note if $a = b =0$ we can conclude nothing.  $1^M = 1$ for all real $M$ so $1^{2x-1} = 1^{1-3y}=1^{3x-1}=1^{2y -2}$ tell us nothing except $x,y, 2x-1, 1-3y,3x-1, 2y-2$ may be any values whatsoever.

If $a \ne 1$ and $b = 1$ we have $a^{2x-1} = 1 = a^{3x-1}$ so $2x-1 = 0 =3x - 1$ which is impossible.

Likewise $a=1;b\ne 1$ gives us the impossible $2y - 2 = 1-3y = 0$.

======

I suppose an easier way of doing this would be.  If $a,b > 0$ then

$a^{2x-1} = b^{1-3y}$ so $a^{(2x-1)(3x-1)} = b^{(1-3y)(3x-1)}$.

And $a^{3x-1} = b^{2y-2}$ so $a^{(2x-1)(3x-1)} = b^{(2y-2)(2x-1)}$.

So $b^{(1-3y)(3x-1)} = b^{2(y-1)(2x-1)}$.

So either:

$b = 1$ and either $a = 1$ or $2x-1,3x-1$ and $(2x-1), (3x-1)$ all equal $0$.  As the later is impossible this means $a = b =1$, and nothing can be determined.

Or $(1-3y)(3x-1)=2(y-1)(2x-1)$ and $13xy = 7x + 5y -3$

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid question and I apologize in advance but what happens if one of the variable equals to 1?

Comment: I just added that.  If both are equal to $1$ you can't conclude anything.  If one is equal to 1 and the other isn't then both the poswers of the other variable must equal $0$.  In this case that will be impossible.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @fleablood, I wished you answered my query regrading your thought process in another of my questions about logs.

Comment: It might come with experience but my thought process was nothing more than knowing that for $0<a,b; a,b \ne 1$ then $a^w = a^y \iff w=y$.  So if I could manipulate $a^{something 1} = b^{else 1}\implies a^{somethingelse} =b^{manipultation 1}$ and $a^{something 2}= b^{else 2}\implies a^{somthingelse} = b^{manipulation 2}$ then I'd know $manipulation 1 = manipulation 2$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @fleablood, these types of questions are rare in the math book that I am doing infact they even have an asterisk besides the question to denote that this is special or hard so your insight about thought process is very much appreciated.